# Unable to hide/ dispose keyboard before navigating back to previous screen

Tags: flutter, dart

My objective is simply to go back from the screen I am on without rebuilding the widgets on my previous page, I find that anytime the keyboard is  open the widgets in the previous screen get rebuilt but if I manually close the keyboard by hitting the back button on my phone and then navigate back the widget state is restored,
So I simply want to close the keyboard before I return to the previous page

An example of the page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScreenTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function testFunction;
  final String title;

  const ScreenTwo({required this.testFunction, required this.title});
  @override
  _ScreenTwoState createState() => _ScreenTwoState();
}

class _ScreenTwoState extends State<ScreenTwo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          widget.title,
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            child: Center(child: Text("Back")),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              widget.testFunction(false);
            },
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: 'Enter a search term'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The agreed upon solution from previous post is `FocusScopeNode` but It doesn't work for me, I want to be 100% certain that the keyboard is closed/ disposed of before I return.

```
 GestureDetector(
            child: Center(child: Text("Back")),
            onTap: () {
              FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
              if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                currentFocus.unfocus();
              }

              Navigator.pop(context);
              widget.testFunction(false);
            },
          ),
```

Comment: try this: if (MediaQuery.of(ctx).viewInsets.bottom != 0)    FocusScope.of(ctx).unfocus();

Comment: Thank but I tried it , doesn't work for me .